# Displaying Unnecessary Information

Tags: gui-design, content, dashboard

Again looking to push back on a client ask. We are creating a dashboard account page where a user can edit their plan, cancel, change their billing details etc. The client is set on promoting all 4 of their services/products, regardless of what the user has actually purchased. Basically, they want tabs in the account page for each of the services.

My argument is, as a user that may have never heard of the service nor purchased it, won't this seem odd? A tab for say, catering, when I've never bought nor heard of catering, and will never have a desire for it. I don't have any data to validate this, but I'm trying to find some points.

Thank you!

Comment: It sometimes helps to ask your client what problem their suggestion is meant to solve. Then you can offer to put your heads together and come up with other options.

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree on abstraction when it comes to presenting a clean and user-centric dashboard.

Although, non-intrusive methods of plugging other products and adverting can be used here. Ever noticed the bottom and left sections of the UX Stack Exchange site?
Find the screenshots below. Notice that not all of these are related to the current page and more or less ads. But they are out of the way in a sense that they don't **obstruct important information** but aren't completely **out of the user's sight**

---

[image: related items]
[image: other products of the same company]

Comment: Thank you! We pitched some ideas where the unneeded tabs were links further down the page, or only appeared when a service was purchased. Sadly the client insisted on having tabs. Now the trick is how to incorporate them responsively.

Answer (score 3):

Tabs generally have low discoverability on websites, especially when the user is on the page with an explicit task already in mind (e.g. paying their bill).  If the user has never heard of the other services that are being offered, even if they do notice the tabs, the lack of context or explanation does not offer any incentive to click them. Basically, the introduction of these tabs is more useless than harmful.  Users most likely will not notice them or if they do, not have any reason to click them.  If anything, the only significant harm will be the development work associated with the creation of tabs that no one will click.

Comment: This is true. I'm hoping to, after launch, monitor the click rates on these tabs. Maybe we can use that data to point out "hey... let's revisit how these work." Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of a tab selling anything. If they want to promote another service, why not just do so, even prominently. Put a banner with a button at the top of the page that the user can dismiss. It won't take up any more space than the tabs. Test variations. If they want to promote more than one product, rotate the banners.